# Ear lies or ear sits?

Tags: word-usage

Which verb should be used in the following sentence.

***Our ears (lie/sit) on either side of our head.***

Comment: Is this a test question? Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Mine are "stuck on".

Comment: The ear sits on a pillow.  The ear lies when you listen to certain political commentators.

Comment: It was a question in my little sister's assignment. The instruction is to fill the blank with an appropriate verb. The sentence is 'Our ears _____ on either side of our head'.

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of this answer, the question is very unspecific. In my opinion, both phrases would be *okay*. Let's check some phrases via Google Ngrams:

[image: ear phrases]

> **Legend**
>
> Blue: *ears lie*
>
> Orange: *ears are located*
>
> Red: *ears sit*
>
> Green: *ears are situated*

*ears lie* is a clear favorite according to Google Ngrams, but this might be ambiguous because of the missing context.

Personally, I think *sit* does not fit the image, because sitting is usually thought of as something on top or inside of something else, while *lie* is more general. Therefore, in my opinion, *the ears are located (...)* is a much more general and less awkward, albeit more technical, alternative.

Edit: Side note. On the [Wikipedia page for the ear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear), the (emphasis mine) "*ears of vertebrates **are placed** somewhat symmetrically on either side of the head* (...)". This is also a very general formulation. But:  "*The inner ear **sits** in the bony labyrinth, and contains structures which are key to several senses*". Here, *sit* is used to say that the inner ear is *inside* of something.